# How to pass value from the database when a table cell is selected

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, model-view-controller, mobile-application

I have a URL stored in the database and I am retrieving it in a table view with a navigation controller.  When I click on a table cell, I would like that URL value to go in my detail view controller and it opens a `uiwebview`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a paramater the Detail ViewControllers init method?  You could try passing it as a param there and storing it as a member.  Then in the viewWillLoad function you can use it to set up your UIWebView.

```
@implementation DetailViewController 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil URL:(NSString*)input
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        //class param to store the url 
        self.urlToUse = input;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     //setup UIWebView with urlToUse
     [super viewDidLoad];
}

//...
@end
```